# Bash script для формирования большого blacklist IP ipset iptables

Tags: linux, bash, iptables, ipset

Ребята, кто может подсказать, что не так? Сформировал bash script для  автоматического формирования пула ip в формате nethash (подсетей). Но на выходе список получается как с отдельными ip, так и с подсетями. Пример
40.87.183.236/31
51.120.224.192/28
51.141.8.62
104.46.121.72
...

Не пойму почему формируются и отдельные ip, ведь исходный загружаемый список только с подсетями.

```
 #!/bin/bash

echo "### Blocking Microsoft ###"

# Delete the list if it already exists
ipset -X blacklist

# Creating a new list
ipset -N blacklist nethash

# Download the files of the countries we are interested in and merge them into one list
wget -O microsoftIPv4-agrig.zone https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lord-alfred/ipranges/main/microsoft/ipv4.txt

echo -n "Uploading blacklist to IPSET"
# Read the list of networks and add them to ipset line by line
list=$(cat microsoftIPv4-agrig.zone)
for ipnet in $list
do
ipset -A blacklist $ipnet
done
echo "Completed"
```

Comment: Может можно как-то оптимизировать?

Comment: Во входном файле написано `51.141.8.62/32` А 32 маска это один единственный ip и /32 при выводе просто не отображается

Comment: Вам не bash нужен, а bpf программа.

Comment: @Mike спасибо, понял!

Comment: @0andriy это вроде фильтр сокета. мне кажется совсем не то)

Comment: @eri, bpf - это интерпретатор среды выполнения, там можно очень многое делать, тем более здесь конкретно используется `ipset`, что как бы намекает...

Comment: @0andriy есть примеры? а то я только с pcap использовал

Answer (score 0):

Советую прогнать список через программу `aggregate` https://ftp.isc.org/isc/aggregate/

```
whois -h whois.radb.net -i origin -T route ${ASN} | grep route: | sed -e 's/route: *//g' | aggregate
```

где ASN это origin компании, полученный через

```
whois -h whois.radb.net 40.74.0.0
```

Подсетей /32 размещенных майкрософтом и не перекрытых более широкой сеткой я не нашел.

Программка почему-то не включенна в стандартный набор... нужно ставить из исходников.